# find x y coordinates of selected text within a scrollable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

##### goal

I have a scrollable parent div that has children divs inside of it. The user should be able to scroll within this container, select a bit of text within one of the sibling children, and a box should appear right above the text they highlighted/selected.

---

I have been looking a lot of different resources on StackOverflow regarding this, but so far it has been a bit of a mess. I am able to get the true height of the surrounding parent container (`parentScrollH = parentRef.current?.scrollHeight`) and my thought is, perhaps I can capture the Y (offset?) distance of the selection from the bottom of the parentRef container, but I think an issue with that is I'm accessing the "selected" text from the `window`, which seems to provide coordinates based on the *window* and not in relation to the surrounding scrollable container.

Maybe there is a way to subtract the Y position of the selected text from the bottom of the parent container? That has been current thought ...

Here are some snippets of code I've collected so far, I feel like i'm both close and far from solving this.

- scrollable height of the parent container:

  - `parentScrollH = parentRef.current?.scrollHeight`
- `boundingClientRect` of the selection within the `window`

  - `selection = window?.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect()`

##### general breakdown of the content:

```js
// with React useRef hooks ...

<div ref={parentRef} className="relative overflow-y-scroll">

 <div>
   <p>text</p>
 </div>

 <div>
   <p>text</p> // <-- select this text
 </div>

 <div className="absolute"> // <-- position this container above selected text
  <button>click me</button>
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The selection stuff is an utter pain, especially across browsers. You might be interested in seeing how I implemented it in my library, hopefully at least somewhat helpful to you: https://github.com/oparisblue/selection-utils/blob/master/selection-utils.js#L440

Comment: @Toastrackenigma yeah, no kidding. I didn't even consider its behaviour across browsers. I think I'll simply have to create a positioned absolute container that appears when text has been highlighted and be happy with that. No fancy medium-esque selection toolbars for me. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create separate component for each child element and add ref to those elements and recalculate the position of the popup based on the position of clicked child element.

***Sample Code***

Parent.jsx

```js
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Child from "./Child";

export default function Parent() {
  const [topPos, settopPos] = useState(0);
  const locateElement = (ele) => {
    debugger;
    var elementTop = ele.current?.offsetTop;
    var divTop = parentRef.current?.offsetTop;
    var elementRelativeTop = elementTop - divTop;
    settopPos(elementRelativeTop);
  };
  const parentRef = useRef(null);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div ref={parentRef} className="relative overflow-y-scroll">
        <Child locateElement={locateElement}>
          <div>
            <p>text</p>
          </div>
        </Child>
        <Child locateElement={locateElement}>
          <div>
            <p>text</p>
          </div>
        </Child>
        <Child locateElement={locateElement}>
          <div>
            <p>text</p>
          </div>
        </Child>
        <Child locateElement={locateElement}>
          <div>
            <p>text</p>
          </div>
        </Child>
        <Child locateElement={locateElement}>
          <div>
            <p>text</p>
          </div>
        </Child>
        <Child locateElement={locateElement}>
          <div>
            <p>text</p>
          </div>
        </Child>

        <div className="absolute" style={{ top: topPos }}>
          <button>click me</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child.jsx

```js
import { useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function Child(props) {
  const eleRef = useRef(null);
  return (
    <>
      <div ref={eleRef} onClick={() => props.locateElement(eleRef)}>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```